# trying to select value on the select dropdown however it is only giving me the text value? contact form 7

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have made a select dropown with times and each given time is given a value eg ([select start-time-friday class:start-time-friday "7:00 am|7.00" "7:15 am|7.25")

My jquery is firing the time in the console log, but not the value I have given it.... eg (I want 7.00 not 7:00am)

[image]

contact form 7 selector values

[image]

I was wondering what was going on? Here is my code for it.

```
$('.start-time-monday').each(function(){
    $(this).change(function(){
        var startTimeMon = $('.start-time-monday').find('option:selected').val() ;
        console.log(startTimeMon);
    })
});
```

Comment: instead of adding pictures, it would be great if you add you select-box HTML,you will get answer answer quickly and correctly. Also `$('.start-time-monday').val()`  will work also.

Comment: Why not just split your selected value with space. `var startTimeMon = $('.start-time-monday').find('option:selected').val().split(' ')[0] ;`

Comment: Please show your dropdown html.

Comment: TomHunt either add an answer of the code which worked for you,or tell us what modification you did in our code to make it working, so that we can modify our answer. You have to then mark the answer to make this question closed for further answers. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get your selected option's text. You are accessing its value.

```
$('.start-time-monday').each(function(){
    $(this).change(function(){
        var startTimeMon = $('.start-time-monday').find('option:selected').text() ;
        console.log(startTimeMon);
    })
});
```

Comment: Were you able to solve it ? Please update the solution.